# Activities to Leads

Tags: reporting

I work in a call center of sorts and we are hoping to create a report that shows how many calls our sales reps are making on each lead before they give up on them.

An issue we are having is that our leads are often recycled and given to different sales reps, so it has been showing activities done by past reps.

Is this possible with basic salesforce? or do we need an app?

Comment: Assuming you are using OOB report type Activities with Leads?  Are you asking to exclude all activities assigned to someone other than the Lead's current owner?

Comment: It sounds like you could group the report by the User who the Activity has been assigned to? This will tell you the number of Activities for each user who's owned the Lead.